# Julia write SymEngine expression to file

Tags: julia, symengine

When i try to write the expressions from the code to file, i receive an error:

`MethodError: no method matching write(::IOStream, ::SymEngine.Basic)`

The code i use is considered to write the expressions to file and then take it from there in other programs. Here's my code:

```
using SymEngine

function Legendre(n)
 @vars x
 a = 1
 Pn = (x^2-1)^n

 for k = (1:n)
     Pn = diff(Pn,x)
     a = a*2*k
        end

       Pn = Pn/a
end

function Asos_Legendre(n,s)
 @vars x
 Pn=Legendre(n)
        for l = (1:s)
            Pn = diff(Pn,x)
        end
        a = (1-x^2)^(s/2)*(-1)^(s)
        Pn = Pn*a

end

function Asos_Legendre_diff(n,s)
 @vars x
        Pn=Asos_Legendre(n,s)
        Pn1 = diff(Pn,x)
        d = (1-x^2)^(s/2)*(-1)^s
        b = x*(-1)^(s+1)*s*(1-x^2)^(s/2-1)
        a = Pn1*d + Pn*b

    open("C:/stj/Julia/test3.txt", "w") do f
            write(f,)
        end
end
```

Maybe there is a way to convert `SymEngine.Basic` objects to `String` and inverse? I could write them as a `String` and then convert them back into `SymEngine` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `ex = convert(Expr,b)` to change the `SymEngine.Basic` into an `Expr`. From there, you can `convert(String,ex)`, or if you attempt to do things like write it to a file then it will automatically convert to a string.

Comment: Thanks for help. I used the `convert` function to make the `SymEngine` output's type `Expr` and `repr` function to change it into string. But now the inverse task is to be made. I read the values from file, turned it into `Expr` by using `parse` function. How can i convert it now to some `f(x)` function analog? For instance, if `3.0x` is the expression, i would like to receive `6` when i put `2` into it. I tried to use the `eval` function but i receive an error `LoadError: UndefVarError: x not defined`

Comment: Here is the code:
`open("C:/stj/Julia/test3.txt", "r") do f`
    `a = readline(f)`
    d = a[2:end]
    b = parse(d)
    println("b")
    println(b)
    println(typeof(b))
    x = 0.5
    c = eval(b)
    println("c=$c")
end`

The content of the `.txt` fie:
:(3.0x)

Comment: That is a different question. StackOverflow is one answer for one question. To ask a new question, make a new question. I am not sure how to answer that one.

Comment: Likely if you're trying to write to a file and then read it back, then writing to a string is the completely incorrect way to do this. Why not just use JLD2 or BSON.jl to do that?

Comment: i've solved it. I used `parse` function to obtain an expression, then gave an `x` to the function and used `eval` function. Here is the code if anybody faces such problem in the future:

`function evaluate(x)
    f = open("/home/fatima/az_cosm_pract/test3.txt", "r")
    a = readline(f)
    d = a[2:end]:
    b = parse(d)
    println("b")
    println(b)
    println(typeof(b))
    #x = 0.5
    c = eval(b)
    println("c=$c")
end`

Comment: Good to hear! If this question is solved then you should mark it as solved so that way it show up as solved in future searches.